# Delete sqlite row in vb with sqlite import

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, delete-row

I have successfully installed sqlite import in my vb project, and I am able to get data from the .sqlite file.However, when I try to delete a row from the same file, I don't get any error but also any result(It doesn't work). The file isn't read only.. So, basically I want the code to delete a row from a sqlite file using vb with sqlite import.

The code I am using:

```vb
Private Sub DelBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DelBtn.Click
    Me.Delete("places", "date = '10/06/2016'")
End Sub

Public Function ExecuteNonQuery(sql As String) As Integer
    Dim cnn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\file.sqlite")
    cnn.Open()
    Dim mycommand As New SQLiteCommand(cnn)
    mycommand.CommandText = sql
    Dim rowsUpdated As Integer = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnn.Dispose()
    cnn.Close()
    Return rowsUpdated
End Function

Public Function Delete(tableName As [String], where As [String]) As Boolean
    Dim returnCode As [Boolean] = True
    Try
        Me.ExecuteNonQuery([String].Format("delete from {0} where {1};", tableName, where))
    Catch fail As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(fail.Message)
        returnCode = False
    End Try
    Return returnCode
End Function
```

Comment: Show the code of what you tried so it can be reviewed.

Comment: SQLite deletes the same as most other dbs.  The code would be required to be able to say what you did wrong.

Comment: I just added the code.

Comment: Well, there are several issues with the code...first, how is the date column defined? SQLite allows date columns to be defined 3 ways

Comment: It is an integer column. `DELETE FROM places WHERE data = '10/6/2016'` works well in a sqlite editor but it does not work in vb

Comment: '10/6/2016' is not an Integer. Try passing it as a parameter in the command

Comment: If your date column is defined as integer, then you are storing the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00` which means there *can* be a time encoded in the value as well depending on how you inserted the data.  If so, '10/06/2016' is unlikely to match it.  Get rid of that SQL helper and use parameterized queries

Comment: But since the query works fine in the SQLite editor, it must work also in this case.. The problem is not in the query.It is on vb. What exactly are parametrized queries and how I use it?

Comment: `since the query works fine in the SQLite editor, it must work also in this case` not true: they are 2 different apps/platforms.  I dont know which "editor" you are talking about, my install did not come with a graphical UI so I had to go find one.  It does its own thing its own way.  If you show the method for adding data so we can see how you are handling the date(s) we might be able to help.  Also, when more than one person comments you need to use @+username if you want to ping someone.  I saw this only because I accidentally left a tab open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption that the queries are the same are misplaced.

That said, here is an example of a parameterized query using your SQL as reference.

```vb
Public Function DeleteFromPlacesByDate(dt As DateTime) As Integer
    Dim rowsUpdated As Integer = 0
    Using connection As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\file.sqlite")
        connection.Open()
        'SQL with parameter included.
        Dim sql As String = "DELETE FROM places WHERE date = @date"
        'create command to execute sql query on connection
        Dim command As New SQLiteCommand(sql, connection)
        'add parameter and value
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dt)
        'Call Prepare after setting the Commandtext and Parameters.
        command.Prepare()
        'execute command
        rowsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()        
    End Using
    Return rowsUpdated
End Function
```

You should also take a look at [SQL As Understood By SQLite: Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

> A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>
> ```
> YYYY-MM-DD
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
> HH:MM
> HH:MM:SS
> HH:MM:SS.SSS
> now
> DDDDDDDDDD
> ```